# Changing state when clicking on button

Tags: reactjs, onclick, state

Button:

```
<button onClick={()=>helpChange(data.setThrough)}>Helped</button>
```

setThrough Function:

```
const helpChange=(helped)=>{
        setData(prevState=>{
            return {...prevState,
                prevState.setThrough?false:true
        }})

    }
```

State:

```
const [getData,setData]=useState([]);
```

Table:

Screenshot of my table

Once user clicked on helped want to change the setThrough to boolean true and return yes inside table and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `helpChange` function as:

```
const helpChange=(helped)=>{
    setData(prevState => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            setThrough: !prevState.setThrough
    }})
}
```

Also, if the `getData` state is an object you shouldn't declare its default value as an empty array:

```
const [getData,setData]=useState(null);
```